# Simple PostgreSQL lookup table is inexplicably slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I'm trying PostgreSQL 8.4.14 for storing **triples**, pieces of data of the form (String, String, String).
For speed, I'm not repeatedly storing strings but rather using two tables:

- **main table `triples`** (subject BigInt, predicate BigInt, object BigInt)
- **lookup table `entities`** (entityId BigInt, name Varying(40000))

I've added **indexes and foreign keys on `triples`**:

- "nsubject_idx" hash (subject)
- "npredicate_idx" btree (predicate)
- "nobject_idx" hash (object)
- "triples_subject_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (subject) REFERENCES entities(entityid)
- "triples_predicate_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (predicate) REFERENCES entities(entityid)
- "triples_object_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (object) REFERENCES entities(entityid)

and also **indexes on `entities`**:

- "entities_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (entityid) CLUSTER
- "name_idx" hash (name)

Now it would be reasonable to assume that lookups are fast. They aren't.

With 151M elements in `triples` and 44M in `entities`, the following query is **immensely slow**:

```
SELECT entityId FROM entities WHERE entityId in (SELECT object FROM triples LIMIT 10000);
```

It's only 10.000 lookups, so I'd expect this to complete at high speed. Query plan:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=288.69..3856.26 rows=43806140 width=8) (actual time=25.226..40110.699 rows=6959 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=288.69..290.69 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=19.445..24.087 rows=6959 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..163.69 rows=10000 width=8) (actual time=0.013..15.792 rows=10000 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on triples  (cost=0.00..2474009.68 rows=151135968 width=8) (actual time=0.012..14.101 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using entities_pkey on entities  (cost=0.00..17.82 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5.756..5.759 rows=1 loops=6959)
         Index Cond: (entities.entityid = triples.object)
 Total runtime: 40112.383 ms
```

What would be happening here?

Note that this is even a *trick query*: because of the foreign key constraint, it is actually equivalent to `SELECT object FROM triples LIMIT 10000`.
For my use case, I'd need the actual lookup.

Comment: What do you see if you create a **btree** index on triples.object?  Also, which PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: I added the btree index, removed the hash index, analyzed again but no noticeable difference.

Comment: Index lookups are reported to take 5.75ms, which indeed  is slow. Try `explain (analyze,buffers) select...` to get information on how much is actually read from disk versus buffers. I would run `vmstat 1` during the query to also see at which rate data is pulled from disk during these 40s and how much I/O-wait occurs.

Comment: @DanielVérité It's PostgreSQL 8, so unfortunately I can't do `buffers`. Here is the output of `vmstat 1`: http://pastebin.com/dLmuJmgY

Answer (score 2):

- Rather than "VARCHAR(40000)" why not use "TEXT"?
- HASH index use is discouraged (see docs at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html).
- Have you run "ANALYZE" on your tables before running the query?
- Giant IN lists can be performance killers.

How do the following queries perform?

```
SELECT e.entityId
FROM entities e
INNER JOIN triples t ON (t.object = e.entityId)
LIMIT 10000;
```

or

```
SELECT e.entityId
FROM entities e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM triples t WHERE t.object = e.entityId LIMIT 10000);
```

Comment: 1. I was told TEXT and VARCHAR are the same (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/476820)
2. I understand, but are those reasons related to performance? Will try BTREE now.
3. I ran ANALYZE on both tables. 4. Those queries are equally slow unfortunately (actually, the last one performs worse).

Comment: TEXT and unconstrained VARCHAR are virtually the same, that is true. You have an upper bound on the VARCHAR length though, but I doubt that has any appreciable impact on your query.

Comment: No difference with BTREE for my query. But the first query you suggested goes way faster now!